# How do I choose an input using a GUI/explorer window in a MATLAB program?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, input, messagebox

I actually have 2 queries:

1. How do I display the data of a variable in a msgbox? In other words, if I have `dist=3765` at the end of my program and I want to display it in a msgbox, how do I do it?
2. I want the user to select an input file (suppose an image) from a folder in my MATLAB program using an explorer window at runtime. How do I code that in MATLAB, or is there an existing function available for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out these MathWorks blog posts ([here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/08/03/more-dialogs-than-you-can-shake-a-stick-at/) and [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/07/20/the-gui-way-of-doing-things/)) from Ken and Mike discussing all of the dialog boxes that you can use in MATLAB. The specific dialog boxes that address the needs listed in your question would be:

- [MSGBOX](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/msgbox.html), which will display a message. You first have to create a string to use as a message. For example, if you have a variable `dist` that stores an integer value you want to display, you can do the following (using the function [INT2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/int2str.html)):

  ```
  hMessage = msgbox(['dist = ' int2str(dist)]);
  ```

  [image]
- [UIGETFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/uigetfile.html), which opens a dialog box for selecting a file and returns the file name and path selected. For example, the following opens up a dialog box to select a MATLAB file (*.m, *.fig, *.mat, etc.) from the current directory:

  ```
  [fileName,filePath] = uigetfile();
  ```

  [image]

Comment: Thanks the info was nice and uigetfile did the trick with imread for reading the image.

Comment: Glad to help! I for one was very relieved when I discovered these various dialog functions... it saved me from having to make them myself. ;)